# How to make Spring Batch process all unprocessed files in a directory with a specific word in the file name

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I will receive one or more files from a client's SFTP server which are stored in our local directory. The file will name will be something like DDMMYYYYHHMMSSIIXCFILE.XSMP#1234567890. So as in the example except for the string "XCFILE.XSMP" the file has a different prefix and suffix which makes the file very unique. Earlier we renamed the file to XCFILE.XSMP and processed through spring batch as below. (My configuration is pretty similar to the post [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/))

```
 <property name="resource" value="file:${XCFILE.XSMP}" />
```

*I have few more use-cases now:*

1. Now we are going to receive multiple files which will be dropped into the same local directory
2. The directory will also have some other files which should not be processed at all (For ex: I only have to process files which have "XCFILE.XSMP" in them)
3. My Spring Batch program should read all the unprocessed files having XCFILE.XSMP one by one and update into our database.

*My question is:*

1. How could I pass multiple files as parameter to Spring Batch. I am
   reading [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope) from spring
2. How can I specify that only XCFILE.XSMP should be considered
3. How to make sure to only process unprocessed files

Please provide me an opportunity to know if any of my case or query is unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple facets to your question:

**How to read in multiple files via Spring Batch.**
The `MultiResourceItemReader` can take a SpEL expression to define the files you're looking to read.  You'd configure the resources property for it to look something like this in your case:

```
<bean id="inputTestReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:some/path/*XCFILE.XSMP*" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="testItemReader" />
</bean>
```

The above example should also address the issue of only reading XCFILE.XSMP files.

**How to make sure to only process unprocessed files**
The typical way of handling that is to move or rename files that have been processed so that they don't match the expression of the files being read.  This can be done with a listener that moves the files as they are completed.